# Crash when using (animation) blocks in switch statements

Tags: objective-c, animation, objective-c-blocks

This code works (if-statement with animations):

```
// works
if (_camOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
        [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0.0))];
    }];
} else if (_camOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
        [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90.0))];
    }];
}
```

This also works (switch-statement without animations):

```
// works
switch (_camOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0.0))];
        break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90.0))];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

This one crashes (switch-statement with animation):

```
// crashes
switch (_camOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
            [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0.0))];
        }];
        break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
            [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90.0))];
        }];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Why can't I use animation blocks in a switch statement?!?

Comment: Give us more details about the crash. What exactly happens? What line is crashing? Is an exception raised or is there some other sort of crash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to :)

Try adding `{ }` around your cases like this :

```
case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait: {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^void{
        [_distanceView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)];
    }];
    break;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks... for making me feel like an idiot ;-) Of course that works now. Is there a Build settings which would give a warning for not using {}?

Comment: There should be - I get one occasionally when I use ARC - something like 'switch statement in protected state' or similar. Though if it compiles it wouldn't expect this to crash :(

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using ARC and activated all warnings now, but still don't get a warning for this specific case. Anyway, thanks ;)